# Use pandoc as documentation generator

Tags: comments, markdown, documentation-generation, pandoc, code-documentation

I saw in a wikipedia page ([Comparison of documentation generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_documentation_generators)) that pandoc can be used as a Documentation Generator (like doxygen does).

But I didn't find in pandoc's documentation or in it's site a way to extract documentation from source code comments, as others documentation generator does.

So how can I use pandoc to do this? There is a way to extract pandoc's markup language from code comments and create a PDF or HTML document from it? Or the wikipedia's comparison list is wrong?

Comment: some work needed, like: http://www.ucalgary.ca/rzach/blog/2014/05/simple-way-to-document-code-with-markdown-grep-and-pandoc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the method described in http://www.ucalgary.ca/rzach/blog/2014/05/simple-way-to-document-code-with-markdown-grep-and-pandoc.html as mb21 mentions a bash script like the one below does the job

```
"makedoc"

#!/bin/bash

grep -e "^%" -e "^$$" $1.tex | cut --bytes=3-| pandoc -f markdown  -o $1.pdf
```